# Send SCP's stdout to Screen and STDERR to File

Tags: shell, stdout, scp, stderr

There's a lot of talk about how redirect both out and err when using SCP, or just stdout itself, but I'm curious if anyone knows how to redirect stderr to a file while stdout continues to be printed to the screen.

Currently, if we redirect stderr like so:

```
scp user@XXXX:*.txt  . 2>errfile.txt
```

Nothing is displayed on stdout, and only errors and echos are captured in errfile.txt.

Comment: Hmm, that's exactly what you did. stdout (progress information) is output to your terminal, with stderr sent to the errfile.txt. BTW, you better protect the star in first argument from expansion: `\*.txt`. Otherwise it will be expanded to filenames on the computer you're on, which is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: I tried this : scp user@XXX:/$PATH/test* . 2> /tmp/test , with openssh client and it's works, i've on sdout all files copied and in "/tmp/test" files with permission denied. Sh -> dash and ssh client : OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it would work

```
MPBAB:work anj$ cat test.sh
echo "Hello there"
echo "This is a test script"

badcommand
MPBAB:work anj$ ./test.sh 2> err.log
Hello there
This is a test script
MPBAB:work anj$ cat err.log
./test.sh: line 4: badcommand: command not found
```

As you can see, when `test.sh` tries to invoke `badcommand` it throws error. However, the two `echo` statements work just fine and shows up at the `STDOUT` and the `STDERR` is logged into `err.log`.

Now implementing the way you tried-

```
MPBAB:work anj$ ./test.sh . 2>err.log
Hello there
This is a test script
MPBAB:work anj$ cat err.log
./test.sh: line 4: badcommand: command not found
```

Works the same way. In your case I am forced to think that the `scp` command you are issuing is not correct. `scp` needs a `source` and `destination`. Something like this (where I want to `scp` test.txt to the remote server)

```
MPBAB:work anj$ scp ./test.txt user@secure.server.com:/home/data 2>scperr.txt
user@secure.server.com's password: #<this is because I dont have the public key installed>
test.txt              100%  291     0.3KB/s   00:00    
MPBAB:work an$ cat scperr.txt
MPBAB:work anj$
```

So you see, that the file is copied and it showed `test.txt   100%  291     0.3KB/s   00:00` in the `STDOUT` and since there were no errors `scperr.txt` was empty.